# Add single quotes around string in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have converted list to string.
but after conversion I am getting string without single quote around the string

for eg:

```
items = ['aa','bb','cc']
items = ','.join(items)
```

output is : aa,bb,cc

expected output: 'aa','bb','cc'

Comment: You can use: `','.join(map("'{}'".format, items))`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to quote the individual strings in the list:

```py
items = ['aa','bb','cc']
items = ','.join([f"'{i}'" for i in items])
print(items)  # 'aa','bb','cc'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is by passing the list into a string formatter, which will place the outer quotes around each list element.  The list is mapped to the formatter, then joined, as you have shown.

For example:

```
','.join(map("'{}'".format, items))
```

Output:

```
"'aa','bb','cc'"
```